# Flutter error Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "H:\Flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\vm_service-7.3.0"

Tags: flutter

Following error popped while running command flutter pub get

**Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "H:\Flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\vm_service-7.3.0".**

[image]

How can I overcome this error.

Answer (score 0):

After a days hard work, this is how i solved it.

1. copied all files from vm_service-7.2.0 to vm_service-7.3.0 (folder location - H:\Flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org)
2. Closed all explorer windows
3. Disabled antivirus
4. Started VScode in admin mode
5. After which I could run following commands

```
flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub get
```